# Multiprocessing with Django - fork causes random deadlocks

Tags: python, django, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I've tried to start Django multiprocess pool with `fork` context, but without any-apparent-reason, sometimes, the main application (that control the pool) freezes, without doing anything else.

This is how I start my pool:

```
model_instances = [instance1, instance2, instance3, instancen]
with multiprocessing.get_context('fork').Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as pool:
    pool.map(_run_par_task, model_instances)
```

After looking at this [page](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/python-multiprocessing/), I've seen that it describes my issue, and I suspect that sometimes, the fork method causes some deadlocks.

So, i've tried to use the `spawn` method to manage my pool, as following:

```
model_instances = [instance1, instance2, instance3, instancen]
with multiprocessing.get_context('spawn').Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as pool:
    pool.map(_run_par_task, model_instances)
```

...but i'm getting this error message:

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

That clearly indicates that Django apps are not loaded in the child process.

Basically, I need to work in the child process with Django models, so, how I can load the Django app in the child spawned processes?

Comment: I once had the same problem, and "solved" it by switching to threads instead of processes. This worked because there the context is shared, but I don't know if it's applicable in your case (depends on what you want to achieve). Moreover, using threads will make your app subjected to the GIL (https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#introduction)

Comment: What i'm seeing is that switching to threads, the function execution is "slowed", in this case maybe the GIL does something that slows down my threads (they do a network request and using the django models saves the result to DB)